RESTful WIQL Interface for Azure DevOps Extension SDK
I'm writing an Azure DevOps extension using the azure-devops-extension-sdk in React.js.  I'm trying to query our existing Product Backlog Items for one with a matching title to get the id for that PBI and update the description as I add new tasks to it.
Is this something that's possible in the Azure DevOps Extension SDK or do I need to import a different library for this interface?
I can't seem to find any documentation on how to authenticate and interface with Azure DevOps Services API.  I haven't found much in regards to authentication.  I've found documentation on what endpoint to use to run my WIQL query and how to format the payload, but I can't find the SDK methods to accomplish those requests.
This documentation points back to the VSS Web Extension SDK, not the current Azure DevOps Extension SDK.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops-rest-7.0
Other documentation refers to utilizing C#, but extensions are written utilizing React.js and TypeScript.

Well, someone offered an answer that has since been deleted which pointed me in the right direction.
This retrieves the access token:
async function getAuthToken() {
    try {
        const token = await SDK.getAccessToken();
        return token;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to get access token", error);
    }
    return "";
}

This runs a query against your work items:
async function queryWorkItems(token: string, query: string, devopsProjectName: string, devopsUrl: string) {

    const response = await fetch(`${devopsUrl}/${devopsProjectName}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=7.2-preview.2`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query })
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error querying work items: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    return result.workItems;
}

This will pull a single work item (to get the current values like System.Description):
async function getWorkItem(token: string, workItemId: string, devopsProjectName: string, devopsUrl: string) {

    const response = await fetch(`${devopsUrl}/${devopsProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error getting work item # ${workItemId}: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}

This will update an existing work item:
async function updateWorkItem(token: string, workItemId: string, description: string, newDescription: string, devopsProjectName: string, devopsUrl: string) {

    const fields = [
        {
            op: Operation.Add,
            from: "",
            path: "/fields/System.Description",
            value: description + newDescription
        }
    ];
    const response = await fetch(`${devopsUrl}/${devopsProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems/${workItemId}?api-version=7.2-preview.2`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(fields)
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error updating work item: ${response.statusText}`);
    }

    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}

So, to pull all of those together, I'm using this function to find my work item, update the description, and return the id:
async function findAndUpdateWorkItemByTitle(title: string, newDescription: string, devopsProjectName: string, devopsUrl: string) {
    try {
        const token = await getAuthToken();

        const query = `SELECT [Id], [Description] FROM workitems WHERE [System.Title] = '${title}'`;
        const workItems = await queryWorkItems(token, query, devopsProjectName, devopsUrl);

        if (workItems.length === 0) {
            console.log("No work item found with the given title.");
            return "0";
        }

        const workItemId: string = workItems[0].id;

        var workItem = await getWorkItem(token, workItemId, devopsProjectName, devopsUrl);


        const updatedWorkItem = await updateWorkItem(token, workItemId, workItem.fields["System.Description"], newDescription, devopsProjectName, devopsUrl);
        return workItemId;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Could not update existing item.");
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
    return "0";
}

I'm still optimizing this, but this was the quick solution to get it working.  Thank you to whomever posted the basis for this which pushed me in the right direction.

Indeed, that document still uses the legacy Visual Studio Teams Service Web Extension SDK.
In addition to the Azure DevOps Web Extension SDK (azure-devops-extension-sdk), please also check the usage of Azure DevOps Web API clients and contracts (azure-devops-extension-api), as well as Azure DevOps UI (azure-devops-ui) if needed ;
Here are some more Azure DevOps Extension Samples for your reference.
